# How to automatically start a linked-to-NppToR R session without GUI in Windows XP

Tags: r, windows-xp, notepad++

I've placed a link to `R i386 2.15.1.exe` in my Windows' automatic execution directory, it's something like

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...\Start Menu\...\Automatic execution\R i386 2.15.1
```

It starts when I log into the machine, and it starts it through the `R` GUI.

If I launch [**`NppToR`**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/), which allows to launch `R` commands from `Notepad++` so that they run in `R` session, it starts a new `R` session instead of using the one opened with the GUI.

At the beginning of my Windows XP session, I would like to automatically start an `R` session at which `NppToR` can link directly: if you run `R` code from `NppToR`, you see that a new `R` session without GUI is started, then I guess that the presence of the GUI could give some issue.

Have you found any solution to this?

Is it possible to have `NppToR` to automatically link to the existing `R` session, though it's already opened with its GUI?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a tricky question.  I contacted the author directly about this issue a while back (I'm using R 302 on Win 7), and he said there are some flaky things about the "guts" of Windows operating systems.  It turned out that one version of Npp2R caused a new R-gui to launch, and the latest version would connect to my existing (running) R-gui.  So you may be in a similar situation under WinXP, which is to say maybe it'll work and maybe it won't.

If you can, try to get a couple different versions of Npp2R from some archive and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll try, let you know. Thank you.